# In node.js, why process.nextTick and runMicroTask runs before setImmediate?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Here is the code piece:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

process.nextTick(console.log, 1)

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log(2)
})

fs.stat('./xxx.js', () => {
  process.nextTick(console.log, 3)
  queueMicrotask(() => {
    console.log(4)
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(5)
  }, 0)
})
```

the output: 1 3 4 2 5

I don't understand why 3 and 4 runs before 2, because according to [what-is-the-event-loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop), when event loop hits the Poll Phase and scheduled with setImmediate, it will not wait but go directly into Check Phase, so setImmediate callbacks should be run first, but obviously it's not, but why?

Comment: `nextTick` is processed BEFORE the next run of the event loop.  `setImmediate` is processed in the next run of the event loop.  There are dozens of articles that explain how `setImmediate`, `process.nextTick` and `setTimeout` are ordered.  A simple Google search will find you many articles to read.

Comment: thx, I do read some articles, but doesn't know setImmediate always runs in the next tick?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `fs.stat` have something special behavior. You could use other fs function like `fs.readFile`, then you'll get the `1 2 3 4 5` like below. (Note: your `xxx.js` file should exist)

```js
const fs = require('fs')

process.nextTick(console.log, 1)

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log(2)
})

fs.readFile('./xxx.js', (e, s) => {
  process.nextTick(console.log, 3)
  queueMicrotask(() => {
    console.log(4)
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(5)
  }, 0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because setImmediate is not in a I/O callback, its callbacks will be executed in next Eventloop iteration when executed outside of Polling phase.